# Checkstyle Automatic Fix Without Editor?

Tags: java, checkstyle

Is it possible to have checkstyle automatically fix the style warning and errors that it can automatically? I know this is possible with `rubocop -a`. I'm looking for a similar behavior here.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible. You have to fix your checkstyle violations manually.

Comment: Do you know why that is? Is it just a feature that hasn't been implemented or is there something from the tech side that isn't possible about it?

Comment: I don't remember people asking for this feature but it has gained some notice in the last few months. It hasn't been delved into much at Checkstyle so there isn't anything preventing someone from discussing and trying to implement it. One limitation is some violations can't be fixed without human intervention like bad variable names.

Comment: Totally. That is true in rubocop as well (some violations can't be fixed), but fixing the ones it can like spacing and single v. double-quotes saves a lot of tedious work.